# Should I sanitize all Special Characters within the $output?

Tags: php, wordpress, sanitization

I have created my own Custom Admin Page, within the WordPress Dashboard.  Within this Admin Page, I have created a 'Social Media' section.  It is my first time doing this, so I am following various YouTube Tutorials, as guidance.

I have successfully created the various settings, however I have learnt that it is recommended to 'sanitize your callbacks'.  Would I be right in thinking that this is a security measure?

This is the function I am using:

```
function theme_name_sanitize_twitter_handler( $input ){ 
    $output = sanitize_text_field( $input );
    $output = str_replace('@', '', $output );
    return $output;
}
```

Have I read right that sanitization is security related and if so, are there any other special characters, other than '@' that I would need to 'sanitize' (apologies if I have used the terminology in the wrong context).

If there are many special characters I would need to sanitize, is there a way to 'sanitize all' rather than manually sanitize them individually?

Comment: I think there should be a twitter spec on what the permitted handle characters are. Your best bet is to find and follow that

Comment: Thanks for your input @apokryfos.  Whilst I am currently working on the Twitter input/output, I would like to know if it is generally 'good practice' to avoid special characters all together.  I have heard about 'Code Injection' and as I am not 100% clued up on code injection, I am just wondering if certain characters would help with code injection and if so, should I avoid such special characters in my $output :-)

Comment: What do you want to do with the output? Display as Html? Take a look at [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). `str_replace` also support arrays, eg: `str_replace(['@', 'foo', 'bar'], '', $input)`

Comment: Christian Gollhardt:  At the moment, I am just working on a Twitter field, within my Custom Admin Page.  According to the YouTube Tutorial I am watching, it states that it is good practice to eliminate the '@' from the $output.  There is a brief reference to code injection but I am not 100% on this area.  Just wondering if I should ensure any other potentially malicious special characters should be eliminated from my strings - Both with Twitter and my other fields.  Also, thanks for the link!  :-)

Comment: @Craig the problem isn't the characters, it's remembering how you're handling them. For example if you're allowing any character to be inputted in the database you need to remember to escape special characters when you output things on screen. Some cases require you to keep special characters while for others removing them is better (the handle case is a strict "only allow what Twitter allows" case)